# How can I store and access javascript variables from a Blogger page (in which contains a poll) without hosting the blog from my own server?

Tags: javascript, html, database, blogger

I do not want to lose the information gathered from a user each time they are generous enough to give me feedback via the poll. And the code isn't complete, but the general idea is there. I apologize if this question has already been adressed, but I looked around before considering writing this post.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
        function sendForm() {

        var previousPollResults;
        // array read from webpage which will be added to.

        for (var i=0; i < document.pollForm.choice.length; i++) {
            if (document.pollForm.choice[i].checked) {
                previousPollResults.choice[i]+=1;
            } else {
                //nothing
            }
        }
```

```
    <form name="pollForm">
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="java" checked />Java<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="webDesign">Web Design<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="blogging" checked />Blogging<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="arduino">Arduino<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="digitalElectronics" checked />Digital Electronics<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="onlineResources">Online Resources <br>


        <input type="button" value="send" onclick="sendForm()">
    </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using a Blogger page and NOT hosting your own site, I'm assuming they should have a poll tool setup.

If I remember correctly you wouldn't be able to save any data on/from the site besides COOKIES through JS which wont let YOU keep track of your poll, only the users own polling information when they visit.

READ THIS: [Blogger Poll](http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=42077)

And this may be an alternative: [Server Sided Proxy on Blogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117343/server-sided-proxy-on-blogger)

Or this: [Custom Embedded Poll](http://www.bloggingehow.com/2012/02/3-steps-to-make-free-custom-embedded.html)

And: [Polls for Blogger](http://bloggerfordummies.blogspot.com/2007/10/polls-for-blogger.html)

Comment: In my experience cookies are used to maintain information unique to each viewer, but I need information that will be universal and the same for all visitors and poll takers. I was hoping maybe there is a site that can provide me a small amount of space for a custom database.

Comment: @Brian if there is I wouldn't know it and this isn't the place to ask advice, Stack Overflow is here to answer direct coding issues with code answers. If you want advice I think that's what the Programmers Stack Exchange site is for.

Comment: I want to know what code would I write to store variables into databases in Blogger

Comment: @Brian I don't think you completely understand what you are trying to do, A)You would need to know AJAX B)You would need somewhere to host a database. C)You would need to have server side code serve your request for the information from the database and hand it to javascript on the page. D)You don't need to, Blogger provides a polling tool. If you need something more complex than the Blogger tool, don't use Blogger.

Comment: I find it insulting that you assume I haven't tried the poll feature in blogger already. The poll feature does not support the flexibility I desire on my blog.

Comment: @Brian Then don't use Blogger, you aren't going to get flexibility there or any other blogging site that gives you free space. If you want flexibility be ready to spend some money (webhosting and domain), and possibly learn to build your own personal blogging site, it really isn't that hard, the hardest thing is security.

Comment: @Brian *"I find it insulting that you assume I haven't tried the poll feature in blogger already"* - We try not to assume anything here, no reason to be insulted.